# mule JDBC with Message Enricher

Tags: mule

I want to Enrich some variables. This is my scenario i am having customer pojo with id, username , password.while i am passing only ID on customer pojo, while on enricher i have read ID value from customer pojo and fetch username and password form DB and append with that pojo.please any one help me how to resolve this...

```
</cxf:jaxws-service>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <enricher doc:name="Message Enricher">           
                    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="selectData" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Database (JDBC)">
                        <jdbc:query key="selectData" value="SELECT Username, Password from Credentials where ModuleId=101"/>
                    </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
                    <enrich target="#[variable:Username]" source="#[groovy:payload.Username]"/>                        
                </enricher>
                 <logger level="INFO" message="Username #[groovy:payload]" />
```

how can read the value from DB and append with my customer Pojo.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC outbound is for writing to the database, inbound for reading.

So use a `jdbc:inbound-endpoint` instead of a `jdbc:outbound-endpoint`.